# Strange White Box in New Apartment

Tags: electrical, interior, security

I just moved in my new apartment and there are 3 small white boxes without any label. (There is also a separate smoke detector and a door bell system, so it shouldn't be that)

This is how it looks inside:
[image: Inside]

Anybody got a clue what that is?

Comment: Google "en1723" and you will know

Comment: Thanks, I just googled for 033519 and couldn't find anything. But now the question why is there temperature transmitters, there is AC system or anything?

Comment: Couldn't tell you how the system works, perhaps it's zoned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Inovonics Wireless   SKU: EN1723
>
> The Inovonics EN1723 provides internal measurement and external thermistor options in a single device. The on-board sensor is excellent **for monitoring ambient indoor temperature**, and the external sensor is user selectable to match your application.

([source](http://www.midwestbas.com/store/inovonics_en1723.html))

Like Tyson notes, these are used in *zoned systems*.  The receiver should be located near your equipment: presumably a larger white box; most likely with the name [Inovonics](http://www.inovonics.com/products/temperature-monitoring/) on it.

These are wireless; should you ever have a problem with a single zone, check their batteries first.